# SQLDeveloper configuration on Mac

Tags: macos, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm a student and need to practice Oracle SQL queries since we have Advance SQL in our syllabus. I have Intel-based MacBook Pro running Mac OS X Snow Leopard 10.6.8. I just downloaded the SQLDeveloper for Mac and unzipped it. The application executed and started well. But I'm not able to create any connections. I get the following error:

> Status: Failure -Test Failed:IO Error: The network adapter could not
>   establish the connection.

When I key in the following parameters:

- Connection name: hr.
- Username: hr.
- Password: hr
- Connection type: Basic
- Role: default
- Hostname: localhost
- Port: 1521
- SID: orcl

Am I doing anything wrong? Do I need to install anything else? I'm newbie so please co-operate with me if I have ignored anything. I also Googled this error, found lot of search results but couldn't solve my problem. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Flagged to be migrated to [dba@stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com/faq)

Comment: "Hostname: localhost". Do you have Oracle Server installed on that computer? And are you even supposed to, or should you connect to some server at school?

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed dataBase first. i think you need to install db and then try to establish connection using sqlDeveloper.i too have same problem